# Using markdowpdf with grunt - how to set page size on output

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, pdf-generation, markdown

Using [`markdownpdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-markdown-pdf), how can i see the size of the output pdf?

For example - i want to control the height of **each page** to be X pixeld for example, this value will apply to all pages.

Here is the relevant part of my `GruntFile.js` + sample `.md` file

---

#### GruntFile

```
var classy = require("remarkable-classy"),
    Remarkable = require("remarkable"),
    md = new Remarkable();

module.exports = function(grunt) {

/**
 * Set the grunt tasks
 */
grunt.initConfig({

    /**
     * This task is for converting the markup to pdf
     **/
    markdownpdf: {
        options: {
            remarkable: {
                html: true,
                breaks: true,
                plugins: [require('remarkable-classy')]
            }
        },
        files: {
            src: "md/**/*.md",
            dest: "dest/"
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the required tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-markdown-pdf');

    // The default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['markdownpdf']);

   md.use(classy);

};
```

---

#### .md file

```
Page 1 content (Need to be smaller than whole page)

<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>

Page 1 content (Need to be smaller than whole page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now i have not found any answer on how to set a custom made size to the pdf.

What i did found is this:
You can set the `paperFormat` & `paperOrientation`

```
grunt.initConfig({

    markdownpdf: {
        options: {
            paperFormat: 'Letter',
            paperOrientation: 'landscape',

...
```

> #### options.paperFormat
>
> ```
> Type: String
> Default value: A4
>
> 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'Legal', 'Letter' or 'Tabloid'.
> ```
>
> #### options.paperOrientation
>
> ```
> Type: String
> Default value: portrait
>
> 'portrait' or 'landscape'.
> ```